# DateTime в качестве массива

Tags: php

Возможно ли вывести строку date?

Почему так не выводит?

```
$date = date_create();
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($date['date']);
echo '</pre>';
```

так тоже не выводит

$obj->date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$date = (array)date_create();
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($date['date']);
echo '</pre>';


$date = date_create();
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($date->format('c'));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Как вы вообще до такого додумались, я это вообще не понимаю? (array)date_create();

Comment: @DivMan неодназначный комментарий у вас, это притензия?

Comment: Я никогда такого не видел (array), что это?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php